# unable to call the method in controller from a jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Iam trying to call a page through a controller by clicking a link

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/register",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String register(ModelMap model){
    System.out.println("###########################afs");
    model.addAttribute("signup",new Signup());
    return "register";
}
```

Comment: <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="register">Create an account</a></p>
this is the link to call that method

Answer (score 0):

Try to send a form:

```
<form action="/register" method="get">      
 <p class="message">Not registered? 
 <input type="submit" value="Create an account"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont really need a form, just add the context path

```
<p class="message">Not registered? <a href="/register">Create an account</a></p>
```